# setInterval in Android Default Browser on Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2)

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, setinterval

We just got hold of a Samsung Galaxy S4 for testing our mobile website (running latest Touch-Wiz Android 4.2.2 - build JDQ39).

Straight away we noticed some major issues in our site. After some investigation, I discovered that this seems to be due to `window.setInterval(fn, repeatInterval)` not repeating, and only calling the passed function once.

Please note, there probably isn't a problem with our usage of `setInterval`, as our code works on all our other devices (lots), the chrome browser on the same device, and on desktop browsers.

I've searched, but can't find any mention of this problem. It seems bizarre to me that such a major bug would not have generated more noise.

My question is: Has anyone else seen this problem? Is it the default browser on 4.2.2, or a Touch-Wiz specific problem? Did you find an elegant work-around?

I've come up with a work-around using self-perpetuating `setTimeout(s)` but it's a bit nasty, and I'd rather not have to do it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't actually `setInterval`'s fault at all. Weirdly enough `eval.call(window, 'some js');` seems to stop all intervals from working on this particular browser. Really don't understand how. This is the only phone we've seen it on - it doesn't happen on the stock browser on the S3 (Android 4.2.1).

P.S. The only reason we're doing `eval.call` is to allow make banner ads which use `document.write` to add scripts in a one page dynamic loading app. I'd much rather it wasn't there.